# Google map get title of region

Tags: google-maps

[image]

I can not extract the title of natural region from Google Map geocoder (in Terrain mode). I can only display the name of nearest road from results[0] (red arrow). Is there a way to extract the nearest title displayed on the map (Green Arrow)? Is it available in **results array**?

```
var latlng = {lat: parseFloat(lat), lng: parseFloat(lng)};    
var geocoder = new google. maps. Geocoder;
geocoder. geocode({'location': latlng}، function(results، status) {
if (status === 'OK') {
   if (results[0]) {
   $("#place"). val(results[0]. formatted_address);
   } else {
   //No title found
   }
   } else {
   //window. alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is response on google maps results, in address_components you have a title of region or locality
 I think that you want this `results[0].address_components[2]`

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "1600",
               "short_name" : "1600",
               "types" : [ "street_number" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Amphitheatre Pkwy",
               "short_name" : "Amphitheatre Pkwy",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Mountain View",
               "short_name" : "Mountain View",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Santa Clara County",
               "short_name" : "Santa Clara County",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "California",
               "short_name" : "CA",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "United States",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "94043",
               "short_name" : "94043",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA 94043, USA",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 37.4224764,
               "lng" : -122.0842499
            },
            "location_type" : "ROOFTOP",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 37.4238253802915,
                  "lng" : -122.0829009197085
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 37.4211274197085,
                  "lng" : -122.0855988802915
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJ2eUgeAK6j4ARbn5u_wAGqWA",
         "types" : [ "street_address" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for revealing the complete array. Unfortunately none of the fields contains the name I'm looking for!

Comment: Im sorry, I dont found nothing more for you :(